# PHP Mail Form - Preventing resubmit when click back button in browser

Tags: php, forms, submit

At the advice of some kind chaps on here, I have reworked a contact form.  I am still very much a novice at coding and am still learning a lot of stuff.

I am having an issue with the code I have so far.

The contact form I am making, I am first trying to get the form work without the use of Javascript. I will then be adding client side validation once i've cracked it without js.

I have got all sanitization and validation using a PHP script sorted. My problem is now dealing with resbumissions.

Once the form is submitted successfully, I can clear the relevant inputfields and variables of the PHP script to prevent a resubmit after success, but there is nothing stopping the user simply clicking 'back' in their browser and landing back at the form they just submitted, complete with all the values they entered.  From there they can click submit again and the PHP script runs and sends exactly the same thing.

- The PHP Script and the code for the HTML form are in a file called contact-form-template.php.
- The form is included on a couple of pages; so on the pages where I want the contact form, I am using include('contact-form-template.php').

So does anyone know how I stop form resubmissions when the user hits the back button in their browser.

FYI - I have tried including a headers (location: etc) redirect, on various lines each coming back with:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/test/contact-us.php:152) in /home/user/public_html/test/contact-form-template.php on line 260

Any help appreciated.  Thanks

So I have the actually contact page which is contact-us.php - is all HTML except this line :

```
<?php include('contact-form-template.php') ; ?>
```

And then this is the contact-form-template.php which has the PHP script and the HTML form underneath.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$sender_name        = $_POST['input_name'] ;
$sender_company     = $_POST['input_company'] ;
$sender_email       = $_POST['input_email'] ;
$sender_telephone   = $_POST['input_telephone'] ;
$sender_message     = $_POST['input_message'] ;
$human_response     = $_POST['input_human'] ;
$callback_date      = $_POST['input_date'] ;
$callback_time      = $_POST['input_time'] ;

// Error Messages
$errorMsg_prefix                = "<li>" ;
$errorMsg_suffix                = "</li>" ;
// Name
$errorMsg_Name_Empty            = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter your name (cannot be empty)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_Name_Invalid          = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please your name using valid characters only." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Email
$errorMsg_Email_Invalid         = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a valid e-mail address." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_Email_Empty           = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter your e-mail address (cannot be empty)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Telephone
$errorMsg_Telephone_Invalid     = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a valid telephone number." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_Telephone_Empty       = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter your telephone number (cannot be empty)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Message
$errorMsg_Message               = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a message. Your message should be at least 30 and no more than 3000 characters in length." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Human
$errorMsg_Human_Incorrect       = $errorMsg_prefix . "You have not answered the simple maths question correctly!" . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Callback Date
$errorMsg_callbackDate          = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a valid date for us to call you back on, formatted as dd/mm/yyyy (for example: 31/01/2013)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_callbackDate_ifTime   = $errorMsg_prefix . "You have selected a date for us to call you back, but not a time." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Callback Time
$errorMsg_callbackTime_ifDate   = $errorMsg_prefix . "You have selected a time for us to call you back, but not a date." . $errorMsg_suffix ;


// Server Side Validation
// Input: Name
if ( $sender_name != "") {
    $sender_name = substr(filter_var( $sender_name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 0,49) ;  
    if ( $sender_name == "" ) {  
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Name_Invalid ;
    }
} else {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Name_Empty ;
} 

// Input: Company
if ( $sender_company != "") { 
    $sender_company = substr(filter_var( $sender_company, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,49);
}



// Input: Email
if ( $sender_email != "") {  
    $email_temp = filter_var( $sender_email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 
    if (!filter_var( $email_temp, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {  
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Email_Invalid ;
    }  
} else {  
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Email_Empty ;
}  


// Input: Telephone
if ( $sender_telephone != "") {
    $sender_telephone = filter_var($sender_telephone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ( strlen ( $sender_telephone ) < 11 || strlen ( $sender_telephone ) > 12 ) {
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Telephone_Invalid ;
    }
} else {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Telephone_Empty ;
} 

// Input: Message
if ( $sender_message != "") {  
   $sender_message = filter_var($sender_message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
    if ($sender_message == "") {  
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Message ;
    } elseif ( strlen ($sender_message) < 30 || strlen ($sender_message) > 3000 ) {
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Message ;
    }
} else {  
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Message ;
}

// Input: Human
if ( $human_response != "12" ) {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Human_Incorrect ;
}

// Input: Callback date
$callback_date = filter_var($callback_date, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ( $callback_date != "" ) {
        list ($day,$month,$year) = explode ("/" ,$callback_date );
        if ( (is_numeric($day)) || (is_numeric($month)) || (is_numeric($year)) and strlen($year) == 4 ) {
            if (!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) 
                $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackDate ;
            } else {
                $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackDate ;
            }
        }
    if ( $callback_date != "" && $callback_time == "") {
        $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackDate_ifTime ;
    }


// Input: Callback Time
if ( $callback_time != "" && $callback_date == "" ) {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackTime_ifDate ;
}

// If there are no errors - send the form.
if (!$errors) {

    $sender_ipAddress   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sender_browser     = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    // E-mail headers
    $recipient_email    = "hello@domin.com" ;
    $headers            = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers            .= "Content-type:text/html; charset: utf8" . "\r\n";
    $headers            .= "From: Website\r\n"; 
    $headers            .= 'Reply-To: no-reply@domain.com' . "\r\n" ;

    // Setting the e-mail subject
    $subject            = "Message from the website." ;



    // For database scripting - replace new-line html with carriage return character - Array
    // Placeholders for array
    $sender_message_placeholders = array("\n") ;
    //Replace Values for array
    $sender_message_replaceValues = array("¶") ;
    // $sender_message stripped of new-lines, and replaced with nc-characters.
    $sender_message_stripped = str_replace($sender_message_placeholders, $sender_message_replaceValues, $sender_message) ;

    // Writing the e-mail body.

    //Head - Commmon
    $emailBody  = "
    <head>
    <style type \"text/css\">
    body                                { font-family: Helvetica, Arial ; font-size: 16px ; line-height: 20px ; color: #5e5e5e }
    h1                                  { font-size: 42px ; line-height: 42px ; color: #c1c1c1 }
    div.section                         { padding: 12px ; margin-bottom: 8px ; background-color: #f7f7f7 ; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8 }
    div.section#callback-details        { background-color: #f8e0e0 }
    div.section#callback-details label  { color: #df5c5c }
    div.part                            { margin-bottom: 8px }
    div.part:last-child                 { margin-bottom: 0 }

    label                               { margin: 0 ; font-size: 13px ; line-height: 20px ; font-weight: bold ; color: #80a553  }
    p                                   { margin: 0  }
    p.input-field#sender-message        { white-space: pre-line }

    div#dbImport                        { color: #a1a1a1!important  }
    div#dbImport p                      { font-size: 12px!important ; line-height: 19px ; white-space: normal!important }
    </style>
    </head> 

    <body>
    <html>

    <h1>Message</h1>

    <p class=\"input-field\" style=\"margin-bottom:12px\">A message has been sent.</p>
    " ;

    // If Callback Date/Time are provided
    if ( $callback_date != "" ) {
    $emailBody .= "
    <div class=\"section\" id=\"callback-details\">     
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Callback Date:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$callback_date</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Callback Time:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$callback_time</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->
    " ;
    }

    // Body - Common
    $emailBody .= "
    <div class=\"section\">     
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_name</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Company:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_company</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_email</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">        
            <label>Telephone:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_telephone</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->

    <div class=\"section\">     
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Message:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\" id=\"sender-message\">$sender_message</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->

    <div class=\"section\" id=\"visitor-info\">
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Sender IP Address:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\"><a href=\"http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=$sender_ipAddress\">$sender_ipAddress</a></p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Sender Web Browser:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_browser</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->

    <div id=\"dbImport\">
        <p style=\"font-weight:bold\">IMPORTDB DATA</p>
        <p>NAME/COMPANY/EMAIL/TELEPHONE/MESSAGE/CALLBACK-DATE/CALLBACK-TIME</p>
        <p>#begin#$sender_name#$sender_company#$sender_email#$sender_telephone#$sender_message_stripped#$callback_date#$callback_time#end</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>" ;

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    //mail($recipient_email, $subject, $emailBody, $headers) ;



    // The message to display in the contact form success div
    $success_message = "
    <div id=\"successContainer\">
        <h4>Your message has been sent.  Thank you.</h4>
        <hr>
        <p>Someone will get back to you very shortly.  We aim to respond to all messages within 24 hours.  If your enquiry is super-duper-urgent, why not give us a ring?</p>
    </div>
    " ;

    // Reset the form if successful.        
    $sender_name = "" ;
    $sender_company = "" ;
    $sender_email = "" ;
    $sender_telephone = "" ;
    $sender_message = "" ;
    $human_response = "" ;
    $callback_date = "" ;
    $callback_time = "" ;


    // end 'if there are no errors'


} else {  // if there are errors with the users inputs
    $error_message = "
    <div class=\"errorContainer\" style=\"display: block\">
        <b style=\"display:block\">Oops... it looks like there is a problem with the data you have entered into the form.  Please correct the following errors:</b>
        <ul>
        $errors
        </ul>
    </div>" ;
    //echo $error_message ;
}
}




 ?>



<!-- The HTML Form -->


<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="" class="contact-form clearfix">
<div id="contact_form"></div>
<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<?php if(isset($error_message)) { echo $error_message ; }  ;?>
<?php if(isset($success_message)) { echo $success_message ; }  ;?>
<div id="errorContainer" class="errorContainer">
    <b>Oops... it looks like there is a problem with the data you have entered into the form.  Please correct the following errors:</b>
    <ul />
</div><!--  !#errorContainer-callback  -->
<!--  BEGIN 4 INPUT FIELDS  -->
<div id="input-fields">
    <div id="name-company">
        <label>Name</label>
            <input name="input_name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_name); ?>">
        <label>Company</label>
            <input name="input_company" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_company); ?>">
    </div><!--  ! #name-company -->
    <div id="email-telephone">
        <label>Email</label>
            <input name="input_email" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_email); ?>">
        <label>Telephone</label>
            <input name="input_telephone" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_telephone); ?>">
    </div><!--  ! #email-telephone  -->
</div><!--  ! #input-fields  -->
<!--  BEGIN MESSAGE CELL  -->
<div id="message">
    <label>Tell us a little about what you'd like talk about when we call you back.</label>
    <textarea name="input_message" id="input_message" tabindex="5"><?php if (isset($sender_message)) { echo htmlspecialchars($sender_message) ; } ?></textarea>
</div><!--  ! #message  -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!-- BEGIN Bottom of Form (Date/Time/Human/Button)  -->
<div id="end">
    <!-- BEGIN DATE  -->
    <div id="cell1" class="cell">
        <label>When would you like us to get back to you?</label>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Date" name="input_date" type="date" id="callback-date" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $callback_date ; ?>">
        </div><!--  ! date input container  -->
        <!-- BEGIN CELL-TIME  -->
        <div>
            Time
            <select id="callback-time" name="input_time" tabindex="7">
                <?php if($_POST['submit'] == true) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $callback_time ; ?>" selected="selected">
                    <?php echo $callback_time ; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <option value=""></option>
                <?php } ?>                  
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0900-1100">09:00-11:00</option>
                <option value="1100-1300">11:00-13:00</option>
                <option value="1300-1500">13:00-15:00</option>
                <option value="1500-1700">15:00-17:00</option>
            </select>
        </div><!--  ! subcell -->

    </div><!-- ! #cell1 -->
    <!-- BEGIN CELL-HUMANCHECK  -->
    <div id="cell2" class="cell human-check">
        <label><b> What is 3 + 9</b></label>
        <input id="human-result-callback" class="human" name="input_human" type="number" maxlength="2" tabindex="8"/>
    </div><!-- ! #cell2 .cell -->
    <!-- BEGIN CELL-BUTTON  -->
    <div id="cell3" class="cell">
        <input class="button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Your Message">
    </div><!-- ! #cell3 .cell -->
</div><!--  ! #end  --> 
</form>
```

Comment: You have `contact-us.php:152` (from error) in your code as the handler, yet your code shows as `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` --- which one is it? If you were to split your form/handler in two, you could put your `header('Location: your_file.php');` after your `mail()` function. When you start mixing stuff, you're bound to hit a few bumps and hiccups, *as it were*.

Comment: Apologies, I have removed the form action. I was just experimenting with something when I included that. I am wanting to keep it all on one page.  I arranged it like this at the advice of the guys in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369738/outputting-php-mail-form-errors-to-same-page that post.

Comment: Just to be clear, contact-us.php is just a html page with a php include.  contact-form-template.php is the script and form.  I would want to include contact-form-template.php on multiple pages

Comment: See my answer below. I used your code and placed `header('Location: http://www.example.com');`underneath your: `mail($recipient_email, $subject, $emailBody, $headers) ;` and it worked fine.

Comment: Also change this `$headers .= "From: Website\r\n";` to `$headers .= "From:" . $sender_email . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT (#1)

**Redirection methods:**

JS-based redirection method:

You could use this in place of `header('Location: page.php');` under your `mail()` function.

It's JS-based `echo("<script>window.location = 'your_page.php';</script>");`

and will not throw an error even before headers.

You could use an `href` method also.

```
echo "<a href=\"your_page.php\" target=\"_top\">Click here to return to our website</a>";
```

---

TESTED

Place `header('Location: http://www.example.com');`

underneath your: `mail($recipient_email, $subject, $emailBody, $headers) ;`

and it will redirect with no errors.

Change `http://www.example.com` to the site/page of your choice.

I used `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` as action in my test form using your code.

---

#### Also I suggest you change this in your form:

```
$headers .= "From: Website\r\n";
```

to

```
$headers .= "From:" . $sender_email . "\r\n";
```

---

### Re-write (use as is and change 2 variables for email and header location)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$sender_name        = $_POST['input_name'] ;
$sender_company     = $_POST['input_company'] ;
$sender_email       = $_POST['input_email'] ;
$sender_telephone   = $_POST['input_telephone'] ;
$sender_message     = $_POST['input_message'] ;
$human_response     = $_POST['input_human'] ;
$callback_date      = $_POST['input_date'] ;
$callback_time      = $_POST['input_time'] ;

// Error Messages
$errorMsg_prefix                = "<li>" ;
$errorMsg_suffix                = "</li>" ;
// Name
$errorMsg_Name_Empty            = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter your name (cannot be empty)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_Name_Invalid          = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please your name using valid characters only." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Email
$errorMsg_Email_Invalid         = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a valid e-mail address." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_Email_Empty           = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter your e-mail address (cannot be empty)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Telephone
$errorMsg_Telephone_Invalid     = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a valid telephone number." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_Telephone_Empty       = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter your telephone number (cannot be empty)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Message
$errorMsg_Message               = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a message. Your message should be at least 30 and no more than 3000 characters in length." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Human
$errorMsg_Human_Incorrect       = $errorMsg_prefix . "You have not answered the simple maths question correctly!" . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Callback Date
$errorMsg_callbackDate          = $errorMsg_prefix . "Please enter a valid date for us to call you back on, formatted as dd/mm/yyyy (for example: 31/01/2013)." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
$errorMsg_callbackDate_ifTime   = $errorMsg_prefix . "You have selected a date for us to call you back, but not a time." . $errorMsg_suffix ;
// Callback Time
$errorMsg_callbackTime_ifDate   = $errorMsg_prefix . "You have selected a time for us to call you back, but not a date." . $errorMsg_suffix ;


// Server Side Validation
// Input: Name
if ( $sender_name != "") {
    $sender_name = substr(filter_var( $sender_name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), 0,49) ;  
    if ( $sender_name == "" ) {  
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Name_Invalid ;
    }
} else {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Name_Empty ;
} 

// Input: Company
if ( $sender_company != "") { 
    $sender_company = substr(filter_var( $sender_company, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,49);
}

// Input: Email
if ( $sender_email != "") {  
    $email_temp = filter_var( $sender_email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 
    if (!filter_var( $email_temp, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {  
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Email_Invalid ;
    }  
} else {  
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Email_Empty ;
}  

// Input: Telephone
if ( $sender_telephone != "") {
    $sender_telephone = filter_var($sender_telephone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ( strlen ( $sender_telephone ) < 11 || strlen ( $sender_telephone ) > 12 ) {
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Telephone_Invalid ;
    }
} else {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Telephone_Empty ;
} 

// Input: Message
if ( $sender_message != "") {  
   $sender_message = filter_var($sender_message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);  
    if ($sender_message == "") {  
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Message ;
    } elseif ( strlen ($sender_message) < 30 || strlen ($sender_message) > 3000 ) {
        $errors .= $errorMsg_Message ;
    }
} else {  
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Message ;
}

// Input: Human
if ( $human_response != "12" ) {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_Human_Incorrect ;
}

// Input: Callback date
$callback_date = filter_var($callback_date, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ( $callback_date != "" ) {
        list ($day,$month,$year) = explode ("/" ,$callback_date );
        if ( (is_numeric($day)) || (is_numeric($month)) || (is_numeric($year)) and strlen($year) == 4 ) {
            if (!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) 
                $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackDate ;
            } else {
                $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackDate ;
            }
        }
    if ( $callback_date != "" && $callback_time == "") {
        $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackDate_ifTime ;
    }


// Input: Callback Time
if ( $callback_time != "" && $callback_date == "" ) {
    $errors .= $errorMsg_callbackTime_ifDate ;
}

// If there are no errors - send the form.
if (!$errors) {

    $sender_ipAddress   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sender_browser     = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    // E-mail headers
    $recipient_email    = "email@example.com" ;
    $headers            = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers            .= "Content-type:text/html; charset: utf8" . "\r\n";
    $headers            .= "From:" . $sender_email . "\r\n";
    $headers            .= 'Reply-To: no-reply@domain.com' . "\r\n" ;

    // Setting the e-mail subject
    $subject            = "Message from the website." ;

    // For database scripting - replace new-line html with carriage return character - Array
    // Placeholders for array
    $sender_message_placeholders = array("\n") ;
    //Replace Values for array
    $sender_message_replaceValues = array("¶") ;
    // $sender_message stripped of new-lines, and replaced with nc-characters.
    $sender_message_stripped = str_replace($sender_message_placeholders, $sender_message_replaceValues, $sender_message) ;

    // Writing the e-mail body.

    //Head - Commmon
    $emailBody  = "
    <head>
    <style type \"text/css\">
    body                                { font-family: Helvetica, Arial ; font-size: 16px ; line-height: 20px ; color: #5e5e5e }
    h1                                  { font-size: 42px ; line-height: 42px ; color: #c1c1c1 }
    div.section                         { padding: 12px ; margin-bottom: 8px ; background-color: #f7f7f7 ; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8 }
    div.section#callback-details        { background-color: #f8e0e0 }
    div.section#callback-details label  { color: #df5c5c }
    div.part                            { margin-bottom: 8px }
    div.part:last-child                 { margin-bottom: 0 }

    label                               { margin: 0 ; font-size: 13px ; line-height: 20px ; font-weight: bold ; color: #80a553  }
    p                                   { margin: 0  }
    p.input-field#sender-message        { white-space: pre-line }

    div#dbImport                        { color: #a1a1a1!important  }
    div#dbImport p                      { font-size: 12px!important ; line-height: 19px ; white-space: normal!important }
    </style>
    </head> 

    <body>
    <html>

    <h1>Message</h1>

    <p class=\"input-field\" style=\"margin-bottom:12px\">A message has been sent.</p>
    " ;

    // If Callback Date/Time are provided
    if ( $callback_date != "" ) {
    $emailBody .= "
    <div class=\"section\" id=\"callback-details\">     
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Callback Date:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$callback_date</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Callback Time:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$callback_time</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->
    " ;
    }

    // Body - Common
    $emailBody .= "
    <div class=\"section\">     
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_name</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Company:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_company</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_email</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">        
            <label>Telephone:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_telephone</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->

    <div class=\"section\">     
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Message:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\" id=\"sender-message\">$sender_message</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->

    <div class=\"section\" id=\"visitor-info\">
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Sender IP Address:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\"><a href=\"http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=$sender_ipAddress\">$sender_ipAddress</a></p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
        <div class=\"part\">
            <label>Sender Web Browser:</label>
            <p class=\"input-field\">$sender_browser</p>
        </div><!-- !.part -->
    </div><!-- !.section -->

    <div id=\"dbImport\">
        <p style=\"font-weight:bold\">IMPORTDB DATA</p>
        <p>NAME/COMPANY/EMAIL/TELEPHONE/MESSAGE/CALLBACK-DATE/CALLBACK-TIME</p>
        <p>#begin#$sender_name#$sender_company#$sender_email#$sender_telephone#$sender_message_stripped#$callback_date#$callback_time#end</p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>" ;

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($recipient_email, $subject, $emailBody, $headers) ;

    header('Location: http://www.example.com');


    // The message to display in the contact form success div
    $success_message = "
    <div id=\"successContainer\">
        <h4>Your message has been sent.  Thank you.</h4>
        <hr>
        <p>Someone will get back to you very shortly.  We aim to respond to all messages within 24 hours.  If your enquiry is super-duper-urgent, why not give us a ring?</p>
    </div>
    " ;

    // Reset the form if successful.        
    $sender_name = "" ;
    $sender_company = "" ;
    $sender_email = "" ;
    $sender_telephone = "" ;
    $sender_message = "" ;
    $human_response = "" ;
    $callback_date = "" ;
    $callback_time = "" ;


    // end 'if there are no errors'


} else {  // if there are errors with the users inputs
    $error_message = "
    <div class=\"errorContainer\" style=\"display: block\">
        <b style=\"display:block\">Oops... it looks like there is a problem with the data you have entered into the form.  Please correct the following errors:</b>
        <ul>
        $errors
        </ul>
    </div>" ;
    //echo $error_message ;
}
}




?>


<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" class="contact-form clearfix">
<div id="contact_form"></div>
<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<?php if(isset($error_message)) { echo $error_message ; }  ;?>
<?php if(isset($success_message)) { echo $success_message ; }  ;?>
<div id="errorContainer" class="errorContainer">
    <b>Oops... it looks like there is a problem with the data you have entered into the form.  Please correct the following errors:</b>
    <ul />
</div><!--  !#errorContainer-callback  -->
<!--  BEGIN 4 INPUT FIELDS  -->
<div id="input-fields">
    <div id="name-company">
        <label>Name</label>
            <input name="input_name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_name); ?>">
        <label>Company</label>
            <input name="input_company" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_company); ?>">
    </div><!--  ! #name-company -->
    <div id="email-telephone">
        <label>Email</label>
            <input name="input_email" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_email); ?>">
        <label>Telephone</label>
            <input name="input_telephone" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sender_telephone); ?>">
    </div><!--  ! #email-telephone  -->
</div><!--  ! #input-fields  -->
<!--  BEGIN MESSAGE CELL  -->
<div id="message">
    <label>Tell us a little about what you'd like talk about when we call you back.</label>
    <textarea name="input_message" id="input_message" tabindex="5"><?php if (isset($sender_message)) { echo htmlspecialchars($sender_message) ; } ?></textarea>
</div><!--  ! #message  -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!-- BEGIN Bottom of Form (Date/Time/Human/Button)  -->
<div id="end">
    <!-- BEGIN DATE  -->
    <div id="cell1" class="cell">
        <label>When would you like us to get back to you?</label>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Date" name="input_date" type="date" id="callback-date" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $callback_date ; ?>">
        </div><!--  ! date input container  -->
        <!-- BEGIN CELL-TIME  -->
        <div>
            Time
            <select id="callback-time" name="input_time" tabindex="7">
                <?php if($_POST['submit'] == true) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $callback_time ; ?>" selected="selected">
                    <?php echo $callback_time ; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <option value=""></option>
                <?php } ?>                  
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0900-1100">09:00-11:00</option>
                <option value="1100-1300">11:00-13:00</option>
                <option value="1300-1500">13:00-15:00</option>
                <option value="1500-1700">15:00-17:00</option>
            </select>
        </div><!--  ! subcell -->

    </div><!-- ! #cell1 -->
    <!-- BEGIN CELL-HUMANCHECK  -->
    <div id="cell2" class="cell human-check">
        <label><b> What is 3 + 9</b></label>
        <input id="human-result-callback" class="human" name="input_human" type="number" maxlength="2" tabindex="8"/>
    </div><!-- ! #cell2 .cell -->
    <!-- BEGIN CELL-BUTTON  -->
    <div id="cell3" class="cell">
        <input class="button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Your Message">
    </div><!-- ! #cell3 .cell -->
</div><!--  ! #end  --> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Are you getting it work even when including the php file with the script and html form on the contact-us page?

Comment: @user2705521 You're welcome. That, I didn't create a file. I guess I should be getting back to the 'ol drawing board, as it were.

Comment: @user2705521 Where is `include('contact-form-template.php');` supposed to go? Is `contact-form-template.php` this file, your contact form? I take it you want to include it in your web site?

Comment: Thanks :) I am surprised this part is so hard to fix.  You would think that there would be a simple expression you could use that would prevent these resubmissions.

Comment: @user2705521 Headers can be a pain in the neck at times. We all eventually learn it the hard way, yet... it's still considered "learning" ;-) will this work for you?

Comment: the pages index.php and contact-us.php are the pages where I would want to include contact-form-template.php.  index and contact-us php files are predominantly html with bits of PHP here and there.

Comment: @user2705521 Ah I see. Well, I might have to leave for a bit, I'll see what I can do when I get back. Worse case scenario, you could use a Javascript `window.location` redirect method, if all else fails. Yet, I might have another trick up my sleeve ;-)

Comment: OK thank you again! Re: JS, as part of the learning curve I am trying to implement the entire thing without JS.  Although, I am guessing there not going to be many legitimate visitors to my site that would be browsing without JS enabled? So it might be worth me just using JS for this end bit?

Comment: @user2705521 You could use this in place of `header('Location:...` under your `mail()` function. It's JS-based `echo("<script>window.location = 'your_page.php';</script>");`

Comment: I'll have a look into that.  I will spend another hour or so see if I can see what I am trying to accomplish without the use of JS, they I might just give in :)

Comment: @user2705521 You could use an `href` also. `echo "<a href=\"your_page.php\" target=\"_top\">Click here to return to our website</a>";`

Comment: @user2705521 You could use the `<noscript>` method if users don't have JS enabled and use the `href` method in conjunction with it. It's another option. Back in a bit, cheers.

Comment: Hi Fred - just to update - I have decided to accept the fact that at the moment I cannot resolve this without using Javascript or affecting the UX by including the error messages on another page and asking the user to go back.  I checked a couple of other websites with contact forms who seem to implement something similar to what I have and they have not bothered to fix the 'go back in browser and able to resubmit' issue.  I am going to just see how it pans out. I am really only bothered about bots or spammers continually spamming. if that does happen i will re-evaluate

Comment: And my guess is that 99.9% of geniune visitrs will have js enabled, and I will be implementing client side validation/sanitization.thank you again :D

Comment: @user2705521 You could also use a Captcha.

Comment: But the problem I was trying to overcome was when a user has submitted a success form, they can just press back in their browser and all the same values will be in the fields, and I believe that pressing back doesnt refresh the page from history - so a new captcha wouldn't be generated, if that makes sense.

Comment: @user2705521 Actually, Captchas can only be used once, so resubmitting won't work.

Comment: But would the captcha not be generated by the PHP code? from what i have gathered clicking back on the browser doesn't re-execute the php, it just loads what was loaded previously - so the php wouldn't give a new captcha. or am i totally wrong/

Comment: @user2705521 I was looking for this link and found it. I suggest you have a look at this page, I'm sure it's going to help you tremendously: http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Comment: @user2705521 The Captcha if I can say, "has a mind of its own" and clicking back to resubmit won't work because each Captca code is unique and probably using sessions and tokens, which the link I gave you just above this, does just that; it has sessions and tokens, so by using that, you can be guaranteed that it won't be submissible twice.

Comment: I am having a look atyour link now :) I know ive said it a hundred times, but thanks! some good people on here :)

Comment: @user2705521 You're welcome. If you feel that my answer helped you, you can if you wish accept it or upvote it so that others could also learn from it. It's up to you. I'm glad I was able to help to a certain extent. I'm sure you'll find a solution, and I think that by using sessions and tokens, will be the way to go.

Comment: Hi Fred, I just thought I would let you know I THINK I have finally found an answwer - i dont think I can actually post my code on here cause i am not a high ranked enough member. That guide you posted pointed me in the right direction, after I realised that a variable defined in php do not retain when they are refreshed and understood fully what is possible with sessions (like storing data), I have managed to get something i think works :D

Comment: how do i give you reputation?

Comment: @user2705521 There's a white checkmark that you can click, under the arrows to the left at the top of my answer that once turned green is marked as accepted.

Comment: Thanks again. I have set the check mark, hopefully you've got some rep out of it :) If you have time I would be really interested in getting your thoughts of what i have coded.  this is my first real stab at php coding and I've learnt a lot. Would be interesting to know if my code could be improved on. I can provide code and working demo if so. Only if you have time though, not worries if not. The form works, no resubmissions and I have validated/sanitized all input fields so hopefully it is ok!! :D

Comment: @user2705521 You're very much welcome and thank you, yes all is good :) I suggest you use http://www.pastebin.com to post your code into, if you want me to have a look at it. Once you pasted it, and pressed submit, there will be a URL in your address bar that I can use to see your code. I might not have time today, but will look at it and let you know.